# SQL Earliest hour for every day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table like this

[image: table]

And I want to have only earliest time from column time for each day from column date. Rest of table has to be unaffected.

So result would be that for example that I have only time 9:25 for 2018-07-13 and rest of rows with later times for 2018-07-13 are deleted

Comment: Do you need select or delete statement? It is not clear. If select, then you already have answers.

Comment: You probably shouldn't have three or more redundant columns.  Just have one datetime column and cast it to a date or time in your select statement as needed.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. One important part is to actually _ask a question_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete you can use a CTE with ROW_NUMBER window function

```
;WITH cteDups
AS(
    SELECT *, RN=ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY M.Date ORDER BY M.Time ASC)
    FROM dbo.yourtable M
)
--SELECT *
DELETE
FROM cteDups D WHERE D.RN > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function to return all rows

```
select 
   *, 
   min([time]) over (partition by [date] order by [time])
from YourTable
```

Or just the aggregate to remove them

```
select *
from YourTable
inner join
(select whatever, min(FullDate) dt
 from yourtable
 group by whatever) x on x.whatever = YourTable.whatever and x.dt = YourTable.FullDate
```

If the whatever column doesn't matter, and you only want the date and time:

```
Select
   [date],
   min([time])
from YourTable
group by [Date]
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to keep certain records and remove the rest would be by using a CTE with a windowing function to rank (or add rownumbers). Check this out:

```
;WITH EarliestHourEveryDay AS (
    SELECT 
        whatever
       ,FullDate
       ,[date] 
       ,[time]
       ,rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [date] ORDER BY [time])
    FROM TableName
)

SELECT *
FROM EarliestHourEveryDay
WHERE rn = 1
/*
DELETE FROM EarliestHourEveryDay
WHERE rn > 1
*/
```

I have commented out the delete statement so that you can test this first. Run the CTE as-is, and if the result set contains the exact rows which you want, remove the SELECT statement from the CTE and uncomment the DELETE statement and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Group by day and select the MIN time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the MIN function and a GROUP BY clause.

Something like:

```
SELECT date, MIN(time) AS EarliestTime
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Here is an example of this working: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/31cff/5)